# Ubuntu x32 releases or ports?

Tags: 64-bit

I have read about the x32 port of Debian. Now, I wonder if Ubuntu has a x32 port or at least some x32 version of its packages since Ubuntu is based on Debian. It does have some libx32-* packages on the official repository. Can you have or build or convert an existing Ubuntu system to x32 (not really x86)?

There are reasons why. The available memory is about 1.8 GB, about 200 MB is used by the video card. The processor is 64-bit capable. I have custom compiled 64-bit 3.17 Linux kernel and packaged for 32-bit dpkg and it runs.

Comment: are you talking about [this](https://sites.google.com/site/x32abi/) or 32-bit?

Comment: I'm talking about x32-abi not 32-bit.

Comment: I'm not sure why people are voting to close this as not about ubuntu; it certainly is.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu shipped with limited x32 support in 13.04.

However, it isn't planning on providing a full port of x32 packages like Debian.

Ubuntu is simply providing a kernel with the x32 syscalls and a functional tri-arch toolchain with GCC and eglibc.

You need a kernel configured with CONFIG_X86_X32=y